# php file_get_contents doesn't send all parameters

Tags: php, mysql, json

I currently developed my own API so I can use two servers. One Server is asking per file_get_contents and GET Parameters so the other can answer with JSON.Everything works fine until one request with many parameters.

```
$detailjson = file_get_contents("http://domain/api.php?id=$id&api=detailsuche&sart=$sart&latq=$latq&lonq=$lonq&umkreis=$umkreis&location=$location&warmmiete=$warmmiete&mietemin=$mietemin&mietemax=$mietemax&wohnqmmin=$wohnqmmin&wohnqmmax=$wohnqmmax&zimmermin=$zimmermin&zimmermax=$zimmermax&grundqmmin=$grundqmmmin&grundqmmax=$grundqmmax&baujahrmin=$baujahrmin&baujahrmax=$baujahrmax&garage=$garage&haustiere=$haustiere&badezimmer=$badezimmer&$haustyp&etagenallmin=$etagenallmin&etagenallmax=$etagenallmax&etagenmin=$etagenmin&etagenmax=$etagenmax&vtour=$vtour&sort=$sort");
```

Currently the following things are submitted:

> Array
>   (
>       [latq] => 49.3134606
>       [lonq] => 6.752286499999968
>       [umkreis] => 50
>       [location] => Saarlouis, Deutschland
>       [sart] => 4
>       [warmmiete] => n
>       [6] => 
>       [7] => 
>       [8] => 
>       [9] => 
>       [10] => 
>       [11] => 
>       [12] => 
>       [13] => 
>       [14] => 
>       [15] => 
>       [16] => 
>       [17] => 
>       [18] => 
>       [haustyp] => haustyp[0]=Dachgeschoss
>       [20] => 
>       [21] => 
>       [22] => 
>       [23] => 
>       [24] => 
>       [25] => 
>       [26] => 
>   )

But the JSON response is like following:

> ["49.3134606","6.752286499999968","50","Saarlouis,","4",null,"","","","","","","","","","","","",null,"","","","","","",""]

You see: Why is my location cut off, warmmiete = null and why is haustyp null?

On the JSON Side I'm using
`$XX = htmlspecialchars($_GET['XX']);`

When using the GET Parameter with my browser I get the correct Array back. So something is broken with my file_get_contents... 
I tried url encode and http_build_query but nothing works :(

Comment: What does api.php do? How does it create the json response?

Comment: Actually it should do a mysql query. But somehow (see above) I can't get all parameters so the query doesn't work like I want. But it does simply fetch all rows and sends them via json_encode($test). For the above Example I'm just putting the GETS into a new array and send it back

Comment: Are you using `urlencode` for all parameters before sending to api.php?

Comment: Your example will end the query string at Sarrlouis, because the space ends the query string. You need urlencode to get rid of characters that will mess up the URL.

Comment: what about the [warmmiete] => n? There is no space.

Comment: WOAH!! Damn! With url encode the location field the whole works! I'm feeling really dumb right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the string that you pass to `file_get_contents` has a special character and would end your string somewhere in the middle.

From the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) :

> If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you need to encode the URI with `urlencode()`.